# How can I make the nnetpredint R package handle a linear transfer function at the output node?

Tags: r, neural-network, nnet

I am working in R, and using the nnet package to train a neural network model. I have been experimenting with the nnetpredint package to compute prediction intervals around the model output. How can I modify the nnetpredint package so that it can handle a linear transfer function at the output node, i.e., when I use the linout=T parameter in the nnet() function?